# no service-worker.js file after npm run build in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

After running `npm run dev` no service-worker.js file in build folder.

> I'm also changed `serviceWorker.register()` in index.js
>
> I'm also using firebase in this project.

Here is ***package.json*** file

```
{
  "name": "movie",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "email-verifier": "^0.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

After deploy in firebase ,I got this error.

> serviceWorker.js:97
> Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://***.web.app/') with script ('https://****.web.app/service-worker.js'):
> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

[image]

Comment: same problem here. I tried `npm run build` and all the production files are created in the build folder. However no sign of the service worker....

Comment: In your question I cannot find the service worker in the proyect structure but the error is actually in a service-worker.js. How did you achieve this file? Made it yourself or it was provided by the build process?  Where is it?. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Seems that I was using an outdate npm command or something. With `create-react-app react-pwa` the service work was missing and could not make that work. With `npx create-react-app my-app --template pwa-typescript` and following the intructions [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and solved following these steps in GitHub issue:

It happened after create-react-app upgraded to version 4.x.

The "fix" was to create a dummy app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript
```

And copy over the relevant code:

```
reportWebVitals.ts

service-worker.ts

serviceWorkerRegistration.ts
```

And don't forget the initialization code in index.tsx.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer . can you please give GitHub issue link.

Comment: @himansaeshan Yes, here is it: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9776#issuecomment-728945921

Answer (score 1):

The serviceWorker.js provided by Create React App is only there to register a service worker file ( say sw.js ). Try the following steps and see if it works:

1. Create a sw.js file (this file will hold the logic for your service worker) inside the 'public' folder.
2. Open the serviceWorker.js provided by Create React App and go the definition of the function register.
3. Follow the code, and go to the line where it registers the service worker. It might be along the lines of

   if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/path/to/sw.js').then()
   }
4. Here change the `/path/to/sw.js` to the file you created in the 'public' directory as `/sw.js`.  This corresponds to `hostname.com/sw.js`

Do this and the service worker might get registered. Things become more complicated from here.

GlHf